# What does "old man's milk" mean in this quote?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context, quotes

> I find friendship to be like wine, raw when new, ripened with age, the true old man's milk and restorative cordial.
> — [Thomas Jefferson](https://www.azquotes.com/quote/534799?ref=cordiality)

What does he mean by "old man's milk"?

Comment: Wine for an old man is like milk for a baby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Friendship improves with age. At first it may not be so good but gets better as age progresses. The reference to milk is like that of mother's milk, that which is essential for basic nourishment, which in old age is hard to come by. Adding the reference to a cordial, a welcoming cocktail, gives some adult tone to the description.

Answer (score 1):

Old Man's Milk defined in Joseph Wright's English Dialect Dictionary 1896-1905 is a composition of cream, eggs, sugar and whisky.

I suppose it to be what Americans would call eggnog, which was considered medicinal.

Comment: I found this modern article: [Auld Man’s Milk, the Scots version of Egg Nog](https://downtonabbeycooks.com/auld-mans-milk-the-scots-version-of-egg-nog/?amp=1) which confirms that people use that recipe to this very day.